# Where can I look to see a revealed public key?

Tags: security, public-key

I've read that pub keys aren't exposed until they're spent from.  Can someone show me an example of a transaction prior to the pub key being exposed and then after?  Where do i look?

Answer (score 1):

Just go to any typical, normal transaction on blockexplorer. [Here's a link](http://blockexplorer.com/tx/bf89f7036bde78103b94cf1291c9389a5ed894045cebd5216f04f1a2aa5c5959) to one I picked at random. The input(s) are scripts where the public key and signature are provided to claim the outputs of previous transactions in the `ScriptSig` field. The output(s) are scripts where the public key has not yet been provided and contain only a hash of the public key in the `ScriptPubKey` field.

Comment: thanks for that.  is the Hash160 a combination of RIPEMD160(SHA256)?

Comment: @joe: Yes. It's documented [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Addresses).

Comment: Transaction bf89f7036bde78103b94cf1291c9389a5ed894045cebd5216f04f1a2aa5c5959 is not archived.